# "What a grand and intoxicating foolishness" and "what grand intoxicating foolishness"

Tags: articles, uncountable-nouns

Innocence, foolishness, lunacy, such nouns aren't countable, right? So both of these sentences are right. But which way would you rather use such a sentence? I know google favors the latter, but I wanted to see your opinion.
Isn't it a bit more poetic to use the first one?

Comment: This isn't the right place to ask opinions. Do you have an objectively answerable question about these sentences?

Comment: “The character that I am playing in this movie is a young man named Kim Bong-chul, who has **an innocence unstained** by society or the world.” Also “ Similarly, Charles Schulz created a wholesome world where children held **an unblemished innocence** in the face of modern life's challenges...”

Comment: See the analysis at 'A blinding light ...' which does indeed label {[indefinite article] + [non-count usage]} 'formal / literary'.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers. I don't think there is a fixed yes/ no answer to my question, so that is why I asked for opinions. Certain things are indefinite in English, are they not? I understand this is a place for definite yes / no answers.

Comment: @DuskFall The thing is that soliciting opinions doesn't work in our format. A primarily opinion based question is off topic across the entire Stack Exchange network. I hope that the duplicates I've selected for you here contain answers that help explain when one might be used instead of the other.